# How to Create a Blast of Liquid in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, graphic-effects, fluid-dynamics

I am making a small cartoon-ish fighting game, and one of the weapons is a Hot Coffee Sprayer, which is a shotgun style weapon.  How do I create a thick blast of dark liquid to come from it, with a solid appearance like the repulsion gel in Portal 2?

[image: repoolshoon_gel]

If its too complex, just tell me how make the gun launch a handful individual drops at once rather than a horizontal wall of coffee.

I am not amazing in Unity or C# but I learn easily and I understand the fundamentals of programming very well.  I'm skilled in Python.

Comment: Presumably you've looked at things like particle effects, metaballs, and screenspace fluids? What have you tried based on your research of fluid rendering techniques thus far?

Comment: No, I have not.  If you have an tutorials on hand, that would be great, otherwise I’ll did though the internet myself a bit.

Comment: Heck, I don’t even know how to create a metaball

Comment: In general, you'll want to do your preliminary internet research before asking on StackExchange. Once you've identified a technique you want to try, but you're finding yourself stuck on understanding or implementing the details, you can come here and ask a more specific question about the exact step in the process you need help with.